# How to get range of cells in one cell separated by two blank spaces

Tags: vba, excel, concatenation

I need a vba code to concat range of cell values separated by two spaces into another cell.
For eg.

```
 
a1  a
a2  b
a3  c
a4 blank
a5 blank
a6 d
a7 e
a8 f
```

then value of cell B will be

```
b1  a,b,c
b2  d,e,f
```

This code concats single range and also concat space. I want space to be a delimiter and concat the range after space and loop through it.

```
Sub demo()
    'i = 2
    'if cells(i,2).value
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    MsgBox (lastRow)
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        'Do Until Cells(i, 2).End(xlDown).Row = ""
        If Cells(i, 3).Value = "" Then
            Sheet2.Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i, 1) & " " & Cells(i, 2)
        Else
            Sheet2.Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i, 1) & " " & _
                Cells(i, 2) & "(" & Cells(i, 3) & ")"
        End If
        ' i = i + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this. This solves your first problem. I don't understand if you are presenting another problem in your second part, or trying to explain the first. Anyway, the sub treats a *single* blank as part of the range to process. Example output in the picture.

Just change the input range ("A1:A30" below). It puts the results in the column adjacent to the input data.

```
Public Sub spaced_out()

Dim rr, Ain As Range
Dim AB As Object

Dim rr_out_count As Integer

Set Ain = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A30")
Set AB = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

For Each rr In Ain
    If (rr.Value <> "") Then
            AB.Add rr.Row(), rr.Value
    ElseIf (rr.Value = "" And rr.Offset(1, 0).Value = "") Then
            rr_out_count = rr_out_count + 1
            Ain.Offset(0, 1).Cells(rr_out_count, 1).Value = Join(AB.items(), ",")
            AB.RemoveAll
    End If
Next


End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution...it worked fine. Though after some tries i also worked out a solution for this.. Thanks again and Thumbs up..